# Excel Power Query - add column from SP data source

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have an Excel sheet with data linked to a list from SharePoint Online (thought the Excel Power Query).

In the original SharePoint data source, I have added some colums. Does anybody have an idea how I can add the data to my exising excel file?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Refresh connection to SharePoint list in Excel Power Query. If Power Query has custom logic then change Power Query manually to include newly added columns.